# How do I get Visual Studio Code to display italic fonts in formatted code?

Tags: fonts, visual-studio-code

How do I configure VS Code to support italic styles, like in this picture?

[image]

My current settings:

```
{
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.fontFamily": "Operator Mono"
}
```

Comment: I use Angular and I'm trying to find out also how can this be done. I tried lots of things but I can still not make that work and also in .html files. I have all the required fonts and settings.

Answer (score 132):

## The direct answer to this question is ([*from this github page*](https://github.com/kosimst/FiraFlott)):

#### Add this to settings.json (`ctrl + ,` or `cmd + ,`)

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": [
        //following will be in italic (=FlottFlott)
        "comment",
        "entity.name.type.class", //class names
        "keyword", //import, export, return…
        "constant", //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
        "storage.modifier", //static keyword
        "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": "italic"
      }
    },
    {
      "scope": [
        //following will be excluded from italics (VSCode has some defaults for italics)
        "invalid",
        "keyword.operator",
        "constant.numeric.css",
        "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
        "constant.numeric.decimal.js",
        "constant.numeric.json"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": ""
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can also provide other keywords in `scope` of course. Check [VS Code's documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_textmate-theme-rules) and the [scope keywords](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/scope_naming.html).

#### Explanation:

When you define a font for VS Code (e.g. Operator Mono for the OP), everything is rendered in that font. In order to achieve the look in the OP's image, you need to apply a different font style (italic/bold) to certain elements. Also, if your font has a significantly different italics style (e.g. Operator Mono has cursive ligatures), you will get a similar look to the OP's image.

---

## Other considerations

In order for your *italics* to look different than your normal text, you need to be using a font whose italics, look different. Such a font is OperatorMono (paid), or [FiraCodeiScript](https://github.com/kencrocken/FiraCodeiScript) (free), or [FiraFlott](https://github.com/kosimst/FiraFlott) (free). I personally prefer FiraCodeiScript.

To make the italic characters linked, (not have spacing between them), like writing cursive, you need to enable font ligatures:

[image: Ligature Example]

To do the above, make sure that your settings.json has the following:

```
{
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Fira Code iScript', Consolas, 'Courier New', monospace"
}
```

*The rest of the fonts are not needed, but they are fallback fonts in case that you are missing the first. Fonts with spaces in their names, usually need single quotes`'`. Also, you might need to restart VS Code.*

Comment: I tried this but did not work in .html files. It does not italicize the HTML attributes

Comment: @marknt15 I found that if you add this line to the scope, it will fix HTML attributes. "entity.other.attribute-name"

Answer (score 34):

First of all I know this thread is over a year old, but I was searching for the same thing without changing the main Dark+ theme, so I've put these in the settings.json of vs code, it might not be the most pretty but it works even on any theme you choose that doesn't have italic, and if you want to remove it just put it in comments, I've put the color in comments if you want to change it later!

```
     "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [{
            "name": "Comment",
            "scope": [
                "comment",
                "punctuation.definition.comment"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                //"foreground": "#4A4A4A"
            }
        },

        {
            "name": "Keyword, Storage",
            "scope": [
                "Keyword",
                "Storage"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
        },

        {
            "name": "Keyword Control",
            "scope": [
                "keyword.control"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
        },

        {
            "scope": "entity.other.attribute-name",
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                //"foreground": "#78dce8"
            }
        },


        {
            "name": "entity.name.method.js",
            "scope": [
                "entity.name.method.js"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                //"foreground": "#82AAFF"
            }
        },


        {
            "name": "Language methods",
            "scope": [
                "variable.language"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                //"foreground": "#FF5370"
            }
        },


        {
            "name": "HTML Attributes",
            "scope": [
                "text.html.basic entity.other.attribute-name.html",
                "text.html.basic entity.other.attribute-name"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                //"foreground": "#FFCB6B"
            }
        },


        {
            "name": "Decorators",
            "scope": [
                "tag.decorator.js entity.name.tag.js",
                "tag.decorator.js punctuation.definition.tag.js"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                //"foreground": "#82AAFF"
            }
        },


        {
            "name": "ES7 Bind Operator",
            "scope": [
                "source.js constant.other.object.key.js string.unquoted.label.js"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                //"foreground": "#FF5370"
            }
        },

        {
            "name": "Markup - Italic",
            "scope": [
                "markup.italic"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                //"foreground": "#f07178"
            }
        },


        {
            "name": "Markup - Bold-Italic",
            "scope": [
                "markup.bold markup.italic",
                "markup.italic markup.bold",
                "markup.quote markup.bold",
                "markup.bold markup.italic string",
                "markup.italic markup.bold string",
                "markup.quote markup.bold string"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "bold",
                //"foreground": "#f07178"
            }
        },

        {
            "name": "Markup - Quote",
            "scope": [
                "markup.quote"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                //"foreground": ""
            }
        },
        {
            "scope": "variable.other",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#82fbff"
            }
        },
        {
            "scope": "entity.name.function",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#dfd9a8"
            }
        },
        {
            "scope": "support.function",
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": "italic",
                "foreground": "#dfd9a8"
            }
        },
        {
            "scope": "string",
            "settings": {
                "foreground": "#CE9178"
            }
        },
    ]
},
```

Hope this helps anyone, and sorry again for posting on an outdated post.

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Valiantsin.operatormonodarktheme

Does basically the same thing :)

Comment: True but it's a theme, so you would have to tweak some more if you want to change colors of the text or editor to match your needs. I really don't know if you could have two themes at the same time actually. But thanks for pointing that out ^^

Comment: For me, `Keyword` in `scope` had to be in lowercase: `keyword`.

Comment: Thank you, looks good on mine! Also, if anyone is having issues with Operator Mono on normal/bold, try `"editor.fontWeight": "300"`

Answer (score 26):

Reinstate Monica's answer helped me, but I noticed everything wasn't italic in the same way I found on italic specific themes. I found a more comprehensive list of italic settings from https://github.com/wesbos/cobalt2-vscode/issues/116. Thank @bgarrant on github.

Add this to settings.json (ctrl + , or cmd + ,)

```
"editor.fontFamily": "Dank Mono, Menlo, Monaco, 'Courier New', monospace",
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
              //following will be in italic
              "comment",
              "emphasis",
              "entity.name.method.js",
              "entity.name.class.js",
              "entity.name.tag.doctype",
              "entity.other.attribute-name",
              "entity.other.attribute-name.tag.jade",
              "entity.other.attribute-name.tag.pug",
              "keyword",
              "keyword.control",
              "keyword.operator.comparison",
              "keyword.control.flow.js",
              "keyword.control.flow.ts",
              "keyword.control.flow.tsx",
              "keyword.control.ruby",
              "keyword.control.module.ruby",
              "keyword.control.class.ruby",
              "keyword.control.def.ruby",
              "keyword.control.loop.js",
              "keyword.control.loop.ts",
              "keyword.control.import.js",
              "keyword.control.import.ts",
              "keyword.control.import.tsx",
              "keyword.control.from.js",
              "keyword.control.from.ts",
              "keyword.control.from.tsx",
              "keyword.operator.expression.delete",
              "keyword.operator.new",
              "keyword.operator.expression",
              "keyword.operator.cast",
              "keyword.operator.relational",
              "keyword.operator.sizeof",
              "keyword.operator.logical.python",
              "italic",
              "markup.italic",
              "markup.quote",
              "markup.changed",
              "markup.italic.markdown",
              "markup.quote.markdown",
              "markup.deleted.diff",
              "markup.inserted.diff",
              "meta.delimiter.period",
              "meta.diff.header.git",
              "meta.diff.header.from-file",
              "meta.diff.header.to-file",
              "meta.tag.sgml.doctype",
              "meta.var.expr",
              "meta.class meta.method.declaration meta.var.expr storage.type.js",
              "meta.decorator punctuation.decorator",
              "meta.selector",
              "punctuation.accessor",
              "punctuation.definition.comment",
              "punctuation.definition.template-expression.begin",
              "punctuation.definition.template-expression.end",
              "punctuation.section.embedded",
              "quote",
              "source.js constant.other.object.key.js string.unquoted.label.js",
              "source.go keyword.package.go",
              "source.go keyword.import.go",
              "source.go keyword.function.go",
              "source.go keyword.type.go",
              "source.go keyword.struct.go",
              "source.go keyword.interface.go",
              "source.go keyword.const.go",
              "source.go keyword.var.go",
              "source.go keyword.map.go",
              "source.go keyword.channel.go",
              "source.go keyword.control.go",
              "storage",
              "storage.type",
              "storage.modifier",
              "storage.type.property.js",
              "storage.type.property.ts",
              "storage.type.property.tsx",
              "tag.decorator.js entity.name.tag.js",
              "tag.decorator.js",
              "text.html.basic entity.other.attribute-name.html",
              "text.html.basic entity.other.attribute-name",
              "variable.language",
              "variable.other.object.property"
            ],
            "settings": {
              "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

NEW refined list I use 9/11/2021 Copy the block below

```
"editor.fontFamily": "Operator Mono Medium",
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
"editor.fontSize": 14,
"window.zoomLevel": 1,
"cSpell.languageSettings": [

],
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": [
        //following will be in italic (=FlottFlott)
        "comment",
        "entity.name.type.class", //class names
        
        "keyword", //import, export, return…
        "constant", //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
        "storage.modifier", //static keyword
        "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
        "entity.name.method.js",
        "entity.name.class.js",
        "entity.name.tag.doctype",
        "entity.other.attribute-name",
        "entity.other.attribute-name.tag.jade",
        "entity.other.attribute-name.tag.pug",
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": "italic"
      }
    },
    {
      "scope": [
        //following will be excluded from italics (VSCode has some defaults for italics)
        "invalid",
        "keyword.operator",
        "constant.numeric.css",
        "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
        "constant.numeric.decimal.js",
        "constant.numeric.json"
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": ""
      }
    }
  ]
```

}

Answer (score 13):

You have to specify the font using the filename. If you have a font with an italic face, then this will work (I tried this on Mac).

For example:

```
"editor.fontFamily": "'OperatorMono-LightItalic'",
```

Comment: Note that this makes everything italics. Based on the screenshot provided, it looks like the OP is looking for rule-specific italics. The following answer explains how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50714195/4500152

Answer (score 9):

The following code is fine

```
{
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "editor.fontFamily": "Operator Mono"
}
```

You must have Operator Mono installed on your computer for that to work. It can be downloaded here: https://www.typography.com/fonts/operator/styles/
Current price at the time of writing this is $599.00 for one machine.

If you have the fonts installed and have restarted Visual Studio Code, try changing your theme. Some themes do not support the italic style.

Comment: Not that it's the Operator font set that costs money. Operator Mono is a subset that is available for free.

Comment: I switched to material theme and italics worked, thanks for that suggestion!

Answer (score 9):

First download a zip file from [here](https://github.com/kencrocken/FiraCodeiScript). Then unzip it and install every file that has the *.ttf* extention by double clicking on it. After that go to VS Code and open settings with *CMD + ,* or *CTRL + ,* (on Windows machines) and type *font*. Under font family paste this *'Fira Code iScript'* (include single quotations). This will start using fira code as the main font now.
Only thing remaining is to add settings and tell VS Code when to actually utilize recursive fonts. For that, still in settings, type *token color* click on Token Color Customizations - open it in settings.json and paste this sucker in:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "textMateRules": [
          {
            "scope": [
              //following will be in italic (=FlottFlott)
              "comment",
              "entity.name.type.class", //class names
              "keyword", //import, export, return…
              "constant", //String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
              "storage.modifier", //static keyword
              "storage.type.class.js", //class keyword
            ],
            "settings": {
              "fontStyle": "italic"
            }
          },
          {
            "scope": [
              //following will be excluded from italics (VSCode has some defaults for italics)
              "invalid",
              "keyword.operator",
              "constant.numeric.css",
              "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
              "constant.numeric.decimal.js",
              "constant.numeric.json"
            ],
            "settings": {
              "fontStyle": ""
            }
          }
        ]
    },
```

That should do it for you! Remember to save the settings file!

Answer (score 6):

```
"editor.fontFamily": "Operator Mono Medium",
"editor.fontLigatures": true,
"editor.fontSize": 14,
```

Also restart VSCode after this.

Comment: You can also change it from medium to light.

Comment: Are you on Linux? If so change the font family to "Operator Mono Book". And bdw make sure the Color Theme supports italics. Try Material Operator.

Answer (score 3):

To make the vs code in italic format, please follow the below proceedure:

Step 1: Install [Fira Code iScript](https://github.com/kencrocken/FiraCodeiScript) (install them locally by opening `.ttf` files after downloading form github - [direct link](https://github.com/kencrocken/FiraCodeiScript/archive/refs/heads/master.zip))

Step 2: You've to install [Dark++ Italic](https://github.com/idbartosz/vscode-darkpp-italic) theme.([VS Code direct link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=idbartosz.darkpp-italic))

- In VScode press `ctrl/command + p` to launch the command palette then run command:

```sh
ext install idbartosz.darkpp-italic
```

Step 3: Open VS Code setting in JSON and add the following lines

```json
{
  ...
  "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code iScript",
  "editor.fontLigatures":  true,
  "editor.fontSize": 14,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Dark++ Italic",
  ...
}
```

Step 4: Now your editor will be awesome as you think. If you wanna do further customization, you can try the below instructions too.

VS Code uses the [TextMate grammar](https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars) syntax to define how it needs to render code. You can refer the [official doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide) for further clarity. Still in settings.json, you can override the font style for the current theme by modifying the `textMateRules` under `editor.tokenColorCustomizations`.

You can find the sample as below:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
      {
          "scope": [
              // the following elements will be in italic
              //   (=Fira Code iScript)
              "comment",
              "keyword.control.import.js", // import
              "keyword.control.export.js", // export
              "keyword.control.from.js", // from
              // "constant", // String, Number, Boolean…, this, super
              "storage.modifier", // static keyword
              "storage.type.class", // class keyword
              "storage.type.php", // typehints in methods keyword
              "keyword.other.new.php", // new
              "entity.other.attribute-name", // html attributes
              "fenced_code.block.language.markdown" // markdown language modifier
          ],
          "settings": {
              "fontStyle": "italic"
          }
      },
      {
          "scope": [
              // the following elements will be displayed in bold
              "entity.name.type.class" // class names
          ],
          "settings": {
              "fontStyle": "bold"
          }
      },
      {
          "scope": [
              // the following elements will be displayed in bold and italic
              "entity.name.section.markdown" // markdown headlines
          ],
          "settings": {
              "fontStyle": "italic bold"
          }
      },
      {
          "scope": [
              // the following elements will be excluded from italics 
              //   (VSCode has some defaults for italics)
              "invalid",
              "keyword.operator",
              "constant.numeric.css",
              "keyword.other.unit.px.css",
              "constant.numeric.decimal.js",
              "constant.numeric.json",
              "comment.block",
              "entity.other.attribute-name.class.css"
          ],
          "settings": {
              "fontStyle": ""
          }
      }
  ]
}
```

Step 5: How to identify the tokens

To identify the TextMate token scope for a given element open up the command palette (`ctrl + shift + p`) and search for `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`. This will bring up the `Scope Inspector` (opens new window)where you can get the identifier of the element you want to configure. Now you just have to click on the element you want to inspect and vscode will show you a list of matching scopes.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wants to change exactly what you want, take the .json structure on the above answer and then take a look at this site at section **12.4 Naming Conventions**

https://macromates.com/manual/en/language_grammars

You can change literally every element on every code line you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

In my case on **MacOS**, after following all the steps with still no sucess, I realized that the fonts had not been installed correctly.

You need to install the whatever regular fonts first, and then the crucial step was to Drag&Drop the Italic version (or any other version) onto the installed one.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After checking the given answers, don't be demotivated.
Maybe you, like me, didn't install all the fonts that comes in the package.
In my particular case after i installed Firacode iScript Regular along with the Bold and Italic packages, the thing worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is somewhat an old question but I found myself on this thread when I was trying to set up operator mono on my Windows machine and had to spend sometime on it to make it work but if anyone else is looking for this it turns out it's as simple as the following on VS Code:

1. Install Operator Mono Dark Theme
2. Add the following to your settings.json:

```
"workbench.colorTheme": "Operator Mono Dark Theme",
"editor.fontFamily": "Operator Mono Light"
```

and that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to install a theme optimized specifically for Operator Mono. On VSCode marketplace there are [quite a few of them](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=%22operator%20mono%22&target=VSCode&category=Themes&sortBy=Installs) including Solarized.