# Is there a way to italicize comments in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code version 1.11.2. I need to be able to see italicized comments in any language file, or at least JavaScript, Python, C, and C++. Is there a general setting for that or is there a programmatic way I can achieve that at the moment?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Victor. Putting this in my settings file (Visual Studio Code 1.42.1) did the trick:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "scope": "comment",
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": "italic"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

You can see selector scopes by pressing `ctrl/cmd + shift + p`, and looking for `Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes`.

You can apply settings to multiple scopes by providing an array:

```jsonc
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "textMateRules": [
    {
      "name": "Comment",
      "scope": [
        "comment",
        "comment.block",
        "comment.block.documentation",
        "comment.line",
        "comment.line.double-slash",
        "punctuation.definition.comment",
      ],
      "settings": {
        "fontStyle": "italic",
        // "fontStyle": "italic underline",
        // "fontStyle": "italic bold underline",
      }
    },
  ]
},
```

Related: [How do I get Visual Studio Code to display italic fonts in formatted code?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50714195/6172657)

Comment: This is much easier to do and work in any theme, thanks.

Comment: Love this! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Found so many answers that advocated making a CSS and then linking to that and blah blah...yet Jason has figured out an easy, effective, and elegant way to do this using only the JSON file we all (should) know. My comments are now unitalicized and bolded. I couldn't be happier. +Respect Jason

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there are ways to accomplish this.

This answer applies to Microsoft Windows (version 10.0.14393) and Visual Studio Code 1.14.2.

If you are using an installed theme from the Extension MarketPlace, their files are located at `C:\Users\<YourUsername>\.vscode\extensions\`.

Let's say you are using Kal.theme-glacier. The theme file is this:

`C:\Users\<YourUsername>\.vscode\extensions\Kal.theme-glacier-0.0.1\themes\glacier.tmTheme`

Edit the file in any text editor (Notepad++ recommended)
**Visual Studio Code should not be running while editing theme files or you may need to restart Visual Studio Code.**

Find the key name `Comment` and change the `FontStyle` to `italic`. The final block of code should look like this:

```
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Comment</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>comment</string>
    <key>settings</key>
        <dict>
            <key>fontStyle</key>
            <string>italic</string>
            <key>foreground</key>
            <string>#515c68</string>
        </dict>
</dict>
```

If you are using a default theme (not installed from the Extension MarketPlace), then the location is here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-<name>`.

Let's say you are using Light+ (default light) theme.

The file you want to look at first is
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-defaults\themes\light_plus.json`

You will find there's no `Comment` key in here but you'll notice `"include": "./light_vs.json"` Then this is actual file you want to edit.
Final block in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\theme-defaults\themes\light_vs.json`should look like this:

```
{
    "scope": "comment",
    "settings": {
        "foreground": "#009000",
        "fontStyle": "italic"
    }
},
```

Comment: `Edit the file in any text editor (Notepad++ recommended)` ... `or you may need to restart VS-Code` Well, I think I can do with that.

Answer (score 6):

A more complete answer is posted on the Visual Studio Code GitHub issue tracker:
[Disable Italic Option Feature Request #32579 (Themes)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/32579#issuecomment-341502559)

For example:

> `punctuation.definition.comment` to disable italic on the characters that creating comments (like: // and others).

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [
        {
            "scope": [
                "comment",
                "punctuation.definition.comment",
                "variable.language"
            ],
            "settings": {
                "fontStyle": ""
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -5):

You can check out *[Optimizations in Syntax Highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2017/02/08/syntax-highlighting-optimizations)*.

It mentions nothing about comments being an eligible scope for theming Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Downvoted because the article is a technical one explaining how themes are rendered, but not how to set them up.