# Visual Studio Code 1.17.2 override font style

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to override VSC's default theme style (e.g. italic or bold for comments) using user setting instead of editing the file like this suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43657779/is-there-a-way-to-italicize-comments-in-visual-studio-code)?

I've done it with colours as described [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/theme-color-reference) but cannot find any document from Microsoft about styles.

Setting the style in user setting can override any theme (at least the default ones) you use so you don't have to edit a file every time you change the theme.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[settings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "textMateRules": [{
        "scope": "comment",
        "settings": {
            "fontStyle": ""
        }
    }]
}
```

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers#_textmate-theme-rules