# VSCode - Change color of typescript function decorator

Tags: visual-studio-code, decorator, syntax-highlighting

Is there a way to change the syntax highlight color of decorators in VSCode? Given the small example :

```
     @HostListener('mouseenter')
     onMouseEnter() {}
```

Both `@HostListener` and `onMouseEnter` are highlighted in the same color. I want to change that. 
So far I tried messing with `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": { "functions" : "SomeColorHere"}}`, but this changes **both** the decorator and the function declaration.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my config to use [TODO highlight](https://github.com/wayou/vscode-todo-highlight) as [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571516/10632388) advised, i excluded `require` and `import` to avoid interfering with js and stylus

[image]

> quick note on the screenshot: the `default` italic style is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320848/how-do-i-get-visual-studio-code-to-display-italic-fonts-in-formatted-code), and the inline property is from [here](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields)

```
"todohighlight.isEnable": true,
"todohighlight.isCaseSensitive": true,
"todohighlight.keywordsPattern": "@(?!require|import)[\\w-_.]*",
"todohighlight.defaultStyle": {
    "color": "#1E88E5",
    "backgroundColor": "0",
    "fontWeight": "bold"
},
"todohighlight.include": [
    "**/*.js",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.vue",
],
"todohighlight.exclude": [
    "**/node_modules/**",
    "**/bower_components/**",
    "**/dist/**",
    "**/build/**",
    "**/.vscode/**",
    "**/.github/**",
    "**/_output/**",
    "**/*.min.*",
    "**/*.map",
    "**/.next/**"
],
"todohighlight.maxFilesForSearch": 5120,
```

Comment: It also highlights decorators inside comments, how to disable that?
Also, if importing a type like `'@types/sequelize'`, it is also `highlighted`.

Answer (score 3):

The caveat from [Marks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571516) is resolved [since 2021](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114082).

You can now use the following to configure the colors:

```json
{
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
      "textMateRules": [
        {
          "scope": "meta.decorator.ts entity.name.function.ts",
          "settings": {
            "foreground": "#e100ff",
            "fontStyle": "bold"
          }
        },
        {
          "scope": "meta.decorator.ts punctuation.decorator.ts",
          "settings": {
            "foreground": "#e100ff",
            "fontStyle": "bold"
          }
        }
      ]
  }
}
```

The first rule is for the name of the function and the second is for the `@` symbol itself.
It might not be perfect as all functions that are used in the context of a decorator are now that color (e.g. `@Decorator(new SameColorClass())` ), but it is already quite an improvement.

Comment: Do you know how to also include brackets '()' into it?

Answer (score 1):

See [inspecting textmate scopes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47272835/how-can-i-make-a-vscode-theme-recognize-c-sharp-interfaces/47274837#47274837) and similar for how to see the scope of your syntax.  So something like this will change the color of the decorator symbol `@` :

```
 {
    "scope":  [
       "punctuation.decorator.js", 
        // "meta.decorator.js",
     ],

     "settings": {
        "foreground": "#e100ff",
        "fontStyle": "bold"
     }
}
```

This only affects the `@` symbol, I couldn't find a way to color the @ symbol and its associated function name and no other function names.

There is a workaround that could do that if you really want it.  And that is to use a word highlighter like [TODO highlight](https://github.com/wayou/vscode-todo-highlight) and make a  regex that does what you want.  Like:

```
"todohighlight.keywordsPattern": "@[\\w-_]*",

"todohighlight.defaultStyle": {
    "color": "red",
    // "letterSpacing": "1px",
    // "backgroundColor": "rgba(170,102,0,1)",
    "backgroundColor": "transparent",
    // "borderRadius": "4px",
    "isWholeLine": false
  }
```